# jQuery template quotes

Tags: jquery, debugging, escaping, jquery-templates, string-interpolation

For example:

```
<span class="'"+${Status}+"'">${Name}</span>
```

I am trying to set my CSS class to the status of the user whose name I am showing.

The above syntax is wrong.

How can I embed a value like `${Status}` in  quotes?

Comment: it's not clear to me why you need to do that

Comment: i have 3 status ,each 3 status has diifrent css classes.if a person is live his status is live and i have to show his name in green clour

Comment: Where is the data kept and in what format? ${Status} is saying wrap an object "Status" in Jquery and then return the Jquery object. which wont work.

Comment: please show more code. In particular, where and how you're using `<span class="'"+${Status}+"'">${Name}</span>`

Comment: class=' ${Status} ' solved my iisue

Answer (score 0):

Use a single quote delimiter:

```
 <span class='${Status}'>${Name}</span>
```